# Two way binding in a custom input field in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having problems getting access to the text am entering into a custom input field using the v-model vue directive, here are the codes for both the custom input component and the App.vue

This is my custom input field

**Input.vue**

```
<template>
    <label >{{label}}</label>
    <input v-model="bindTo" type='type'  required>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['label','type','bindTo']
}
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>

    <!-- Email -->
        <Input type="email" label="Email" :bindTo="email"/>
        <p>Email : {{email}}</p>


</template>

<script>
import Input from "./Input.vue";

export default {
    components:{
        Input,
    },
data() {
    return {
        email:"",
        password:"",
        role:"developer",
        terms:false,
        tempSkill:"",
        skills:[],
        passwordError:"",
        emailError:"",
    }
},


</script>
```

I can't have access to the value in the email in my data method. What might be wrong?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#usage-with-v-model

Comment: @MichalLevý thanks for the link to the docs it was extremely useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through the docs thoroughly I found the solution that helped solve my problem

**Input.vue**

```
<template>
    <label >{{label}}</label>
    <input :value="modelValue" type='type' @input="$emit('update:modelValue',$event.target.value)"  required>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['label','type','modelValue'],
    emits:['update:modelValue']
}
</script>
```

Then in **App.vue**

```
<template>

    <!-- Email -->
        <Input type="email" label="Email" v-model="email"/>
        <p>Email : {{email}}</p>


</template>

<script>
import Input from "./Input.vue";

export default {
    components:{
        Input,
    },
data() {
    return {
        email:"",
        password:"",
        role:"developer",
        terms:false,
        tempSkill:"",
        skills:[],
        passwordError:"",
        emailError:"",
    }
},


</script>
```

For more details visit the docs as there are other ways to make it work aside this approach https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

Answer (score 0):

In Vue.js, you just simply add `v-bind="$attrs"` and `v-on="$listeners"`, so you can forward everything from parent to child component.

**Input.vue**

```html
<template>
    <label >{{label}}</label>
    <input v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners">
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['label']
  }
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>

    <!-- Email -->
        <Input type="email" label="Email" v-model="email" required/>
        <p>Email : {{email}}</p>


</template>

<script>
  import Input from "./Input.vue";

  export default {
    components: {
      Input,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        role: "developer",
        terms: false,
        tempSkill: "",
        skills: [],
        passwordError: "",
        emailError: "",
      }
    },
</script>
```